# OpenGL render rate (onDrawFrame) with camera surface

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm writing an android app with a GLSurfaceView (OpenGL ES 2.0) on top of a SurfaceView used for camera live preview.

Android version used: 2.3.3, compiled to API level 8.

I've extended GLSurfaceView.Renderer and measured the rate of *onDrawFrame* calls. On Samsung Galaxy S I get ~55.6fps, on LG G2x ~58.9, but on htc Sensation 4G I get **only ~17-22fps**.

The following experiments **didn't** make a difference to this rate:

- removing ALL code from the *onDrawFrame* except for the very light rate measurement code
- used setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY) and set a timer to call *requestRender* every 17ms.
- disabled most of the other things my app does.

I've made two other experiments:

1. Disabled the camera preview by commenting out Camera.startPreview() ==> got **30.3 fps**.
2. (1) + Set the camera preview surface visibility to INVISIBLE ==> got  **59.94 fps**.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Is this some kind of a limitation with the htc device (hardware)? Any ideas on what else I can do to debug this problem or to get a higher frame rate?

Thanks!

Edit:
another piece of (probably useless) information: when I ran this [OpenGL Frame Rate Test app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mortalpowers.android.openglfpstest&hl=en) on my htc it showed 60fps...